# How can I use immediate: true in watch but at the same time get access to values of created hook in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am using the following watch:

```
watch: {
    $route: {
        immediate: true,
        handler(newVal) {
            if (some condition ...) {
                this.getItems()
            }
        },
    },
},
```

However in the first time when you load the page it throws some data with value of null in console errors. The reason is that their values are getting set in created hook. How can I remove those errors by letting first call of the **getItems** method in watch happen when created hook is called but at the same time use `imediate:true`?

Comment: You should raise a flag inside the `created` hook - and then check for this flag in your `some condition`.

Comment: What do you mean by raising a flag?

Comment: I mean setting a variable to boolean TRUE value.

Comment: Set the data property value to something that will never happen during the execution of your code, and check for that value in the watcher to skip it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether I got your question right, but:

- When immediate is set to true, the watch handler gets called at create time, with the value currently available, then, after that, at each value change
- When immediate is set to false, the watcher only gets called at each value change, AFTER the component was created.

I guess you must first decide which one to use, then handle the circumstances.